# How to see ruby c extension backtrace info

Tags: c, ruby

here my output, I don't understand the hex "0xe8" and "0x7f8c783ac74d";

```
/home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_article/c/ro_helper_article.so(get_article_n2+0xe8) [0x7f8c783ac74d]
```

[here](https://gist.github.com/roroco/0abdfb89734934286ff2) is full output

Comment: We need a bit more context. How is this produced, what is it supposed to be, what do you want to use it for, What have you tried so far to determine what these hex values are? And You should describe your question entirely in the question and not split vital information in question adn title.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've caused (or, rather, a plugin caused) ruby to segfault.  This normally means that you've attempted to access memory outside of your designated bounds - basically, your program did something really, really weird.  The line you specifically picked out is actually a C library - the `.so` extension means "[static object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library)," and is linked into the main ruby executable.  The information it's providing you with tells you where the error originated - however, most production libraries do not contain information such as "file names" and "line numbers".  Instead, they contain a [list of symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table).  In your case, it's telling you exactly where, in the static object, an error originated - exactly `0xe8` bytes after the `get_article_n2` symbol - or, at the address `0x7f8c783ac74d`.

So now you have a few options.

1. You can poke around blindly in your source code (I'm assuming you wrote the library that is in error here, since it seems that's what you're testing) and try and guess where the segfault originated.  You already know that it's in the function `get_article_n2`, considering the error originated after that symbol.
2. You can disassemble the static object to see the specific instruction that caused the error, and then attempt to map it to the source.
3. You can enable debugging, and have your build system output file names and line numbers so you know what you're looking at.  *(disclaimer: I'm not sure if this will work; it doesn't look like you're emitting debug information to me, but I'm not sure if you are; and even if you would be, I'm not sure it would be used to output.  However, this seems the easiest course of action.)*.